# Revert edited image - android

Tags: android, image, edit

I wanted to know if its possible to revert all the changes made to an image by other s/w such as gimp,etc.
I want to make an android app that takes in any pic and returns the original (or close to original) pic.
I googled, but all the results are trivial and none involved the coding part of it.
Thank you

Comment: **No**. It's **impossible**. Once you save the changes to a bitmap, they are **forever**. There is **no history** data. Therefore, you **can't rollback** to a previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Some OS systems (like OSX for Mac) will create versioning for files. If the target OS does this, it is possible to "undo" changes if you can find where the file versions are located. But, you could only do this on the device where the file was edited - not on another device.

Some image editing software will have proprietary formats (like Adobe) that include "layers" or versioning information. If you are talking about those file formats, and not the common "JPG" or "PNG" or "BMP" formats, then it could be possible to write an app that could peel back layers, etc.

However, neither Android nor standard file formats support file versioning or layering. It seems possible that Android might support file versioning in the future, when phones commonly have 10TB of storage (should that ever happen), but in the interim, no. Changes are made to the original file and there is no "undo" option, no artifacts that might allow you to reconstruct the original and no support for other options.